# How to reload my <select> element from a database in Java

Tags: html, database, jsp, html-select

I have submitted some data in database from an html form. Then I have to load one column of that data in a `<select>` of another form. I have done this but how will I increase the number of options as the number of records is increased?

Code is as follows:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>  
<%@ page import="java.lang.*"%> 

<%!
    ArrayList al;
    Object o[];
    String s[] = new String[10];
%>

<jsp:useBean id="c" class="com.ebbeans.ViewBean"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="c" property="*"/>

<% 
    al = c.loadExistingEmpCode();
    o = al.toArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
        s[i] = (String) o[i];
    }  
%>

    ..........
    ..........

        <select name="empCode" size="1" id="empCode">
            <option value="<%= s[0] %>" selected><%= s[0] %></option>
            <option value="<%= s[1] %>"><%= s[1] %></option>
            <option value="<%= s[2] %>"><%= s[2] %></option>
            <option value="<%= s[3] %>"><%= s[3] %></option>
            <option value="<%= s[4] %>"><%= s[4] %></option>
        </select>
```

Here only 5 options will be shown. How would I increase the number of options dynamically when the records are incresed?

Answer (score 2):

To start off, do **not** use scriptlets in JSP. They are replaced by taglibs and EL since a decade. A commonly used taglib is [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) which provides the `<c:forEach>` tag for exact this purpose. With [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) you can seamlessly access back end data in JSP pages.

Here's an examlpe how your code is best to be replaced with.

Employee:

```
public class Employee {
    private Long code;
    private String name;
    // +getters +setters
}
```

EmployeeServlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeDAO.list();
    request.setAttribute("employees", employees);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("employees.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

employees.jsp:

```
<select name="employee">
    <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
        <option value="${employee.code}">${employee.name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Map the EmployeeServlet on `url-pattern` of `/employees/*` and invoke it by `http://example.com/contextroot/employees`. Good luck and keep your JSP scriptletfree :)

Answer (score 0):

I am a c# coder, but I believe you want something like this:

```
    <%@ page import="java.util."%>
    <%@ page import="java.lang."%> 
    <%! ArrayList al = c.loadExistingEmpCode(); 

       for(int i=0; i < ai.Count; i++)
       {

    %>

     <option><%= ai[0].toString() %></option>

   <% } %>
```